# Difference in meaning depending on context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I’m not a native English speaker and I wonder if there is a difference in meaning between the following phrases (hunting lion/lion hunting/the hunt for), depending on the context. The context is: the writer is not just an observer writing about hunting in general, but he uses his own experiences as a hunter for the story. I have the feeling that there must be a difference. Thank you very much! (I Hope I pushed the right button.)
Leo

He went for a safari. Hunting lion provided material for a story.

He went for a safari. Lion hunting provided material for a story.

He went for a safari. The hunt for lion provided material for a story.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct use of 'hunting' (gerund or continuous or past participle?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562987/correct-use-of-hunting-gerund-or-continuous-or-past-participle)

Comment: If you wanted to be clear it was hunting he did rather than hunting he observed, you could say something like "His lion hunting provided material..." Of your examples "Lion hunting" is the most idiomatic but does not indicate who did the actual hunting (and nor do any of the others).